# Llamar Función con un Botón Usando Python-kivy

Tags: kivy

Nuevo en python-Kivy, con un proyecto en mente pero no logro hacer que un boton llame a una función. Les muestro mi código:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

kv='''
GridLayout:
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10
    rows:6
    id: registro

    BoxLayout:
        id: cedula
        Label:
            text:'Cédula'
            font_size: 16
        TextInput:
            id: key
            multiline:False
    BoxLayout:
        id: nombre
        Label:
            text:'Nombre y Apellido'
            font_size: 16
        TextInput:
            multiline:False
    BoxLayout:
        id: Correo
        Label:
            text:'Correo Electrónico'
            font_size: 16
        TextInput:
            id: mail
            multiline:False
    BoxLayout:
        id: carga
        Button:
            text:'Registrar'
            font_size: 14
            on_press: app.reg
        Button:
            text:'Cancelar'
            font_size: 14
'''
class GridLayout(GridLayout):
    def reg():
        print ('El botón si llama la función')

class registroApp(App): 

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv) 

registroApp().run()
```

el error que me arroja es:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Como Pueden observar... el botón 'Cancelar' tampoco esta programado con quit() pues ni idea de como hacerlo...
Agradecido de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Unas cuantas aclaraciones:

- No deberias usar para la clase de tu widget el mismo nombre que el del layout del que hereda:

  ```
  class GridLayout(GridLayout)
  ```

  Aunque funcione puede ser muy confuso.
- Para hacer referencia a la clase padre que defines en python debes usar una construccion del tipo  en kv languaje.
- Por otro lado en debes usara `root` en vez de `app` al llamar a la función.
- Por último para llamar a la función/método debes usar parentesis, sino no la ejecutaras.

Este sería el código funcionando:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

kv='''
<MyWidget>
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10
    rows:6
    id: registro

    BoxLayout:
        id: cedula
        Label:
            text:'Cédula'
            font_size: 16
        TextInput:
            id: key
            multiline:False
    BoxLayout:
        id: nombre
        Label:
            text:'Nombre y Apellido'
            font_size: 16
        TextInput:
            multiline:False
    BoxLayout:
        id: Correo
        Label:
            text:'Correo Electrónico'
            font_size: 16
        TextInput:
            id: mail
            multiline:False
    BoxLayout:
        id: carga
        Button:
            text:'Registrar'
            font_size: 14
            on_press: root.reg()
        Button:
            text:'Cancelar'
            font_size: 14
'''

class MyWidget(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def reg(self):
        print ('El botón si llama la función')

class registroApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    registroApp().run()
```